# setsockopt (sys/socket.h)

Tags: c, prototype, sockets, setsockopt

The prototype for setsockopt is:

```c
int setsockopt(int socket, int level, int option_name, const void *option_value, socklen_t option_len);
```

Are the following all correct? Which are not?
a.)

```c
int buffsize = 50000;
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char *)&buffsize, sizeof(buffsize));
```

b.)

```c
int buffsize = 50000;
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (void *)&buffsize, sizeof(buffsize));
```

c.)

```c
char *buffsize = "50000";
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, buffsize, strlen(buffsize));
```

d.)

```c
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, "50000", 5);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `SO_RCVBUF` option is defined as having a parameter type of `int`, so (c) and (d) are not correct.

> http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tagtcjh_8

Because C will automatically convert an `int *` to `const void *`, no cast is required:

```
int buffsize = 50000;
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &buffsize, sizeof(buffsize));
```

However, because `char *` and `void *` will also be automatically converted, (a) and (b) should also work.